# dissociate Firebase object from current scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let's say I have a list of items:

**list.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span ng-click="editItem(item)">{{item.title}}</span><br>
</div>
```

And I want to edit one of them:

```
.controller('adminCtrl', ["$scope", "angularFireCollection", function($scope, angularFireCollection) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/articles");
  $scope.items = angularFireCollection(ref);

  $scope.editItem = function(item){
    $scope.item = item;
    $scope.updateView('form');
  }

  $scope.updateItem = function(item){
    $scope.items.update(item);
    $scope.updateView('list');
  }

  $scope.goBack = function(){
    $scope.updateView('list');
  }
}]);
```

Clicking `editItem(item)` toggles the `form.html` partial:

**form.html**

```
<div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="goBack()">Go Back</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="item.title">
  <button type="button" ng-click="updateItem(item)">Save</button>
</div>
```

If I edit my current item and `goBack()` before `updateItem(item)` those changes propagate locally --- but obviously should not because I have not yet updated the record.

How do I dissociate a firebase object being passed in through `editItem(item)` from the `$scope.item` variable which it is being set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chandermani's point is correct, but you have to hack your way into clone:
`var clonedItem = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(item));`

This will work!

Comment: Here's a good example:  look at the **collection.update** function at [angularfire.js:399](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js#L399)

Comment: So now when I `updateItem(item)` my console tells me I've lost the `$ref` --- `item.$ref is undefined`. How would I then `$scope.items.update(item);` ?

Comment: I got it --- you need to save your original to keep those `$refs` so later on when updating you can merge them back in `angular.extend({},originalItem,editItem)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a clone of the item using `angular.clone()` method in edit and see if it works

```
  $scope.editItem = function(item){
    $scope.item = angular.copy(item);
    $scope.updateView('form');
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this crashes my browser.